# How to place gridView to the center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

How can I place my programmatically filled gridview to the center of screen.
It is always on the top.
I can place my gridview to the centerm if it is included to the scrollView.
But in this case I can only see first cells of gridview (other not visible)
The XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<include layout="@layout/adview" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >

<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewTopics"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backNormal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/adview" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewTopics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes! Interesting. You just used weight in only one place. Thank you very much!